# How to change width/height of selection using keyboard in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I select a rectangular region using my mouse. Then, using my keyboard, I can move the selection to left and right to the exact position I want.

Can I also change its width/height using keyboard?

Comment: To whom is lookimng for a way on how to change selection with the mouse, simply right click with the mouse on the selection and choose "Transform Selection" from the popup menu. Now the selection will show little squares in corners and you can change its size as you like, you can even rotate it.

Answer (score 13):

To make a "perfect" size selection you could do two things.

### 1st ...Thing

1. Make the selection ( can be quite halfassed selection )
2. Make a Quick mask ( Hotkey: Q )
3. Activate Free transform ( Hotkey: Ctrl+T )
4. Expand the selection to the dimensions you need.
5. Accept Free Transform ( Enter or double click inside Free transform )
6. Hotkey: Q will get you out of Quick mask.

This is also good just for the sake of snapping.

It might seem like many stages but everything together except `4.` can be done in few seconds.

Now that I'm back on my pc, here's informational image:
[image]

### 2nd ...Thing

1. Make the selection ( So that you'd rather have extra than less than you need )
2. Fill the selection with a color ( Reduce opacity if needed )
3. Make another selection ( You can nudge that selection around with your arrow keys and Delete extra off. )

Comment: +1 this one is nice but take some time to do, nice answer by the way

Comment: @Jack Clicking hotkeys for `Quick mask` and `Free transform` take ..I would say one second. Same goes for getting off from both. One that takes time is the moving `Free transform` around and adjusting the width and what ever. But, thats really the case no matter how you do it. So its an excellent way to do this if you can spare few extra secnds to press couple extra hotkeys. And thanks for the +1.

Comment: LOOOOOOOVE using Quick Mask for selections. incredibly flexible and powerful.

Comment: If only there was a keyboard shortcut to move the keyboard focus to the options bar *(is there?)* the edits to the selection could be done solely with keyboard.

Comment: @koiyu No, and you'd still mostlikely need to set the side that you want to stay still, which I would image would be hard to make so that it would work well on keyboard.

Comment: Fantastic answer, just helped me out and I was amazed that this is possible. And +points for including the hotkeys, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can change the selection by an equal number of pixels in height and width,

Go to `select->modify->Expand(to increase)->Contract(to decrease)`

**You can also follow this for exact size marquee selection :**

In the snapshot below (which shows the `options` palette when the selection tool is active) you'd pick "fixed size" style and then enter your desired width and height in just next(width height)box.

[image]
[image]

I am unaware of a way to "nudge" the size of the selection. However, the info palette shows the size of the marquee, and you can then use that information to determine and then manually key in the values you want.

Comment: you can rollback, if its not okay :|

Comment: The "expand" command is not a good answer because "expand" will expand OUTWARD IN ALL DIRECTIONS, when what we want is to expand only horizontally & vertically only.  For example, make a selection on a single pixel, then "expand" 50 pixels, and you will have a beautiful octogon.